# Heroku procfile multiple workers

Tags: python, heroku, procfile

I have two different workers that I would like to run alongside my web app in Heroku.

I currently have the following in the procfile:

```
web: gunicorn project:app
worker: python project/worker/worker.py
worker: python project/worker/processor.py
```

but it only runs the web and the last worker processor as those are the only ones I can see under dynos. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use unique names for each of your worker process-types, e.g:

```
web: gunicorn project:app
worker: python project/worker/worker.py
processor: python project/worker/processor.py
```

Comment: ahhh thanks! I thought "worker" and "web" were specific things!

Comment: only 'web' is special, the other processes can be called anything.